# Switch between perspectives in rcp

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, perspective

I have an rcp application which consist of two perspectives. in one perspective I have a tree. On double clicking any item of the tree it opens the details of the selected tree item but in the same perspective. I want to switch the perspective on double click instead of open the details of the selected item in the same perspective. How can I do it?

My double click listener is

```
 // Add double click listener to open an element editor on double click action:
    getViewer().addDoubleClickListener(new IDoubleClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void doubleClick(DoubleClickEvent event) {
            if (currentTreeSelection instanceof StoreableElement) {
                openElementContentEditor((StoreableElement)currentTreeSelection);
            }

        }
    });
```

The content editor is the part which displays the details of the selected tree item.

```
 public void openElementContentEditor(StoreableElement element) {

    ElementDescriptor ed = DataStoreManagement.getInstance().getElementDescriptorById(element.getDescriptor());
    String editorID = ed.getEditor();
    IDataStoreEditorInput editorInput = DataStoreManagement.getInstance().createEditorInput(element);

    try {
        PlatformUI.getWorkbench()
                .getActiveWorkbenchWindow()
                .getActivePage()
                .openEditor(editorInput, editorID, true,
                        IWorkbenchPage.MATCH_INPUT);

    } catch (PartInitException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the following snippet to switch perspective:

```
IWorkbenchWindow workbenchWindow = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
workbenchWindow.getWorkbench().showPerspective("PERSPECTIVE_ID", workbenchWindow);
```